# C++ define pthreads' function if that function is not declared

Tags: c++, pthreads

Apparently newer versions of ubuntu (22.04 onward) do not have the Pthreads function `pthread_yield` but instead they include `sched_yield`

So my solution is to include a .c file in my project with the following function:

```
#include <sched.h>
int pthread_yield(void) { return sched_yield(); }
```

This solves my problem under ubuntu 22.04, but what about other versions where `pthread_yield` exists?

I would like to define this function only if it is not present in pthreads, how can I do that?

Comment: *I would like to define this function only if it is not present in pthreads, how can I do that?* [RTFM](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html): `#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? Does it mean that if _GNU_SOURCE is present, then there's no need for the fake function? isn't the presence of _GNU_SOURCE a bit too generic?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is the simplified "not present in pthreads". What exactly is " pthreads" ?

At the basic level, `pthread_yield` is not part of IEEE Std 1003 (POSIX) threads.

It is declared in the GNU implementation of `<pthread.h>`, conditional on `_GNU_SOURCE`.

The implementation used to be in GUN's implementation of `libpthread`, but it's being moved to GNU's implementation of `libc` in Ubuntu 22.

Instead of using fake-POSIX functions, it's much cleaner to use the `sched_yield` function. It's been present for ages.

Comment: Sure, but since I'm dealing with the xpress MIP solver, which is closed source I don't have the chance to do it.  All I'm doing is linking with -lpthreads. If the fake pthread_yield function is not there, no pthread_yield function will be found anywhere, hence the compilation fails. The fake pthread_yield function saves the day, but may break things in systems where pthread_yield is naturally present i.e. ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera: That's a bit of a problem then. Unlike Windows, Linux doesn't have first-class support for closed source software. Part of it is the fragmentation - Ubuntu is just one Linux flavor. The core idea has always been to just compile your software locally. (which is why there's no equivalent to the Windows SDK)

Answer (score 1):

With the new comment, it sounds like you have another alternative. Linux traditionally has a library link order that's more predictable than C++ mandates.

In particular, C++ says that violating the One Definition Rule is Undefined Behavior, but `ld` will usually pick the first occurrence of a symbol. So just add your `.o` *after* `-lpthread`.

There are more complicated tricks with *weak symbols* but that shouldn't be necessary here.